# Is there a word that describes inflation that is excessive but not hyperinflation?

Tags: single-word-requests

An example would be the recent inflation in Russia, where the exchange rate of GPB:RUB [has doubled from ~60 in September to ~120 today](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=GBPRUB%3DX%20Interactive#%7B%22range%22%3A%221y%22%2C%22scale%22%3A%22linear%22%7D). 
Hyperinflation was [defined by Philip Cagan in his book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation#Definition) as 50% inflation per month sustained over a year. 
Is there a word or phrase that describes excessive and abnormal amounts of inflation that do not reach hyperinflation levels?

Comment: You can use the adjective 'over-the-top' to describe something that's excessive or exaggerated.

Comment: _Semihemidemisuperhypoinflation_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me, *rampant inflation* is the term that most readily springs to mind for this situation. Or simply *high inflation.*

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to go with some adjectives to describe it: above-average or excessive inflation may work.  Official inflation targets generally define a desired or  acceptable  level of inflation. Numbers above that target may be consider as too high.